# Detect 'Up' UIGesture in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a custom segue in my app connected to a button, which when tapped scrolls my view down to a different view. I need to implement the unwind for the segue, and would like it to occur when the user swipes up when at the top of the `UIScrollView` on the second view.

This is my code for the segue:

```
override func perform() {

    var MainVCView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
    var CreditVCView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    CreditVCView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, screenHeight, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window?.insertSubview(CreditVCView, aboveSubview: MainVCView)


    // Transition.
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        MainVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(MainVCView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)
        CreditVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(CreditVCView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)

        }) { (Finished) -> Void in
            self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have implemented the gesture recogniser, however I can't get it to detect the swipe when it's set to 'Up' or 'Down'. It only works when it's set to 'Left' or 'Right'.

This is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let unwindSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "unwind")
    unwindSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(unwindSwipe)
    view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
}

func unwind() {
    println("Test")
}
```

As you can see, I've tried a few things but I just can't get it to detect the gesture.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see in your code you have a scrollview, are you trying to make the gesture recognized to work on top of it? Because it will "still" the action the scroll the view

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to make it so that once the user scrolls to the top of the scroll view, they can swipe up again and it will segue back to the other view.

Comment: You will need to implement a why to monitor the position of the scrollview and when it gets to the top you can the other view. Another idea is to intercept the gesture and execute the segue if the velocity is greater than some value and scroll the view of its smaller.

Answer (score 0):

add a swipe gesture to

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    var swipeup = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
    swipeup.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeup)
}

func respondToSwipeGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right:
            println("Swiped right")
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
            println("Swiped up")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

and add one line to handle clash
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.requireGestureRecognizerToFail(swipeGesture)